# Count the number of elements between 2 dates conditionally on a variable in R

Tags: r, date, dplyr

I'm trying to count the number of precipitation below a certain threshold (let's say less or equal than 50) between two dates.

Basically, I have a vector `cuts` that contains the dates that I want to count between inclusively. I want to use the `cuts` vector to "subset" the dataset in different bins and than count the number of events where it was raining less than 50 mm of rain.

I'm using dplyr and a for loop at the moment, but nothing is working.

```
set.seed(12345)
df = data.frame(date = seq(as.Date("2000/03/01"), as.Date("2002/03/01"), "days"), 
                precipitation = rnorm(length(seq(as.Date("2000/03/01"), as.Date("2002/03/01"), "days")),80,20))
cuts = c("2001-11-25","2002-01-01","2002-02-18","2002-03-01")
for (i in 1:length(cuts)) {
  df %>% summarise(count.prec = if (date > cuts[i] | date < cuts[i+1]) {count(precipitation <= 50)})
}
```

But I have this error message:

```
Error: no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "logical"
In addition: Warning message:
In if (c(11017, 11018, 11019, 11020, 11021, 11022, 11023, 11024,  :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

This is not working either:

```
for (i in 1:length(cuts)) {
  df %>% if (date > cuts[i] | date < cuts[i+1])%>% summarise(count.prec = count(precipitation <= 50))
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try:

```
df %>%
  group_by(gr = cut(date, breaks = as.Date(cuts))) %>%
  summarise(res = sum(precipitation <= 50))
```

Which gives:

```
# A tibble: 4 × 2
          gr   res
      <fctr> <int>
1 2001-11-25     1
2 2002-01-01     4
3 2002-02-18     2
4         NA    40
```

Or as per mentioned by @Frank - you could replace `summarise()` by `tally(precipitation <= 50)`

Comment: Ok I get it. It's counting the number of `TRUE` or `FALSE` in the `sum` function. When it's not matching, it's reporting an NA?

Comment: @M.Beausoleil Exactly. You have 40 dates outside the ranges specified in `cuts` that have `precipitation <= 50`. Should you want to remove this from the result you could simply add `... %>% na.omit()` or  `... %>% filter(!is.na(gr))` to the chain.

Comment: Just add `%>% 
  filter(!is.na(gr))` at the end to delete the NA row! Thanks! Very clever.

Comment: @M.Beausoleil Glad it helped :)

Comment: Instead of your `summarise`, `tally(precipitation <= 50)` seems to work.

Comment: I don't understand with `tally`, I have this error `Error in tally(., res = sum(precipitation <= 50)) :  unused argument (res = sum(precipitation <= 50))`

Comment: @M.Beausoleil You need `tally(precipitation <= 50)`, no need for the `sum()`. Furthermore you can't use `res = ...` in `tally()`

Comment: Yes it's working too! Interestingly, you don't have to specify anything to handle NAs with `tally`

Comment: If I want to change it to a cumulative sum, would this be the solution: `df %>%  group_by(gr = cut(as.Date(date), 
                    breaks = as.Date(cuts))) %>%  summarise(res = sum(cumsum(precipitation)>= 10, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%   filter(!is.na(gr))`

Answer (score 1):

We can try with non-equi join using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.7+
df2 <- data.table(cuts1 = as.Date(cuts[-length(cuts)]), cuts2 = as.Date(cuts[-1]))
setDT(df)[df2, .(Count = sum(precipitation <=50)),
           on = .(date > cuts1,  date < cuts2), by = .EACHI]
#         date       date Count
#1: 2001-11-25 2002-01-01     1
#2: 2002-01-01 2002-02-18     4
#3: 2002-02-18 2002-03-01     2
```

Comment: I have this error: `Error in `[.data.table`(setDT(df), df2, .(Count = sum(precipitation <=  : 
  could not find function "."`

Comment: @M.Beausoleil  It was recently introduced in the devel version of data.table.

Comment: Yeah, my version is `‘1.9.6’`

Comment: @M.Beausoleil  If you download the devel version, it should work